# Is it possible to get JsonRootName of nested child with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have nested objects that I want to get the root name from when I serialize it to json using jackson. this is the result I want(I apologize to all the flower enthusiasts but just needed a example, this is not to be interpreted as accurate data):

```
{
   "plants": "flowers",
   "types": {
       "rose" : {
           "color": "red",
           "height": 25, 
       }    
   }
}
```

I got 2 classes, one wrapper class:

```
public class JsonWrapper {
    public String plants = "flowers";
    public Object types;
}
```

and the "flower" class:

```
@JsonRootName("rose")
public class rose{
   public String color = "red";
   public int height   = 25;
}
```

now what I do is this:

```
JsonWrapper wrapper = new JsonWrapper();
wrapper.types = new rose();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
```

The result i get is:

```
{
 "JsonWrapper":{
 "plants": "flowers",
     "types": {                  
         "color": "red",
         "height": 25,                    
     }
 }
}
```

So i get the root name for the wrapper object that is not annotated but not for the child object that is annotated. is there a way to tell jackson not to get a root name where there is none and also analyze child objects?

Comment: Is there a constraint that you need to use `JsonRootName` ? Can be done without that.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser Deendayal, I don't need to use `JsonRootName` just thought it existed for that exakt purpose. I will try your solution first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution without `JsonRootName`.

> JsonWrapper.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonWrapper {
    public String plants = "flowers";
    Map<String, Flower> types = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Flower> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(Map<String, Flower> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

> Flower.java

```
public class Flower {
    public String color = "red";
    public int height   = 25;
}
```

> Main.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JsonWrapper wrapper = new JsonWrapper();
        wrapper.getTypes().put("rose", new Flower());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);

    }
}
```